# Trying to get test Unit Cases. Can't figure out how to mock POST HttpClientRequests, am a little stuck

Tags: angular, http, testing, jasmine, case

In trying to figure out how to mock an HttpRequest for one project, I decided I should do it for a simpler project that I created from scratch.

At the moment, I am trying to mock an HTTP POST Request via Angular for Test Cases. The application is just a calculator I built, and I want to mock sending the form data to a back end. However, I seem to have come to a roadbloack.

Here is my calc.service.spec.ts file:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { createSpyFromClass, Spy } from 'jasmine-auto-spies';
import { CalcService } from './calc.service';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Num } from './calc';


describe('CalcService', () => {
  let httpClient: HttpClient;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let cService: CalcService;
 

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        CalcService
      ]
    });

    httpClient = TestBed.inject(HttpClient);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    cService = TestBed.inject(CalcService);
  });

  it('should add a number and return it', () => {
    const newNumber: Num = { number1: 3, number2: 25 };

    cService.addNumber(newNumber).subscribe(
      data => expect(data).toEqual(newNumber, 'should return the number'),
      fail
    );

    // addEmploye should have made one request to POST employee
    const req = HttpTestingController.expectOne(cService.numUrl);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    expect(req.request.body).toEqual(newNumber);

    // Expect server to return the employee after POST
    const expectedResponse = new HttpResponse({ status: 201, statusText: 'Created', body: newNumber });
    req.event(expectedResponse);
  })});
```

and here is my calc.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map, catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'my-auth-token'
  })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CalcService {

  numUrl = "/api/num";
  private baseUrl = "https://localhost:8082/";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  getCalc(): Observable<CalcService[]> {

    return this.http.get<CalcService[]>(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
  

  addNumber(num: Number): Observable<Number> {
    return this.http.post<Number>(this.numUrl, num, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(Number => console.log("employee: " + JSON.stringify(Number))),
        catchError(this.handleError(num))
      );
  }
  private handleError<T>(result = {} as T) {
    return (error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      return of(result);
    };

    
  }
}
```

However, my code isn't working at all for this, and I personally feel that I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're not `flush`ing (sending the response) but you're doing `req.event`.

Try this (check !! line):

```
it('should add a number and return it', () => {
    const newNumber: Num = { number1: 3, number2: 25 };

    cService.addNumber(newNumber).subscribe(
      data => expect(data).toEqual(newNumber, 'should return the number'),
      fail
    );

    // addEmploye should have made one request to POST employee
    const req = HttpTestingController.expectOne(cService.numUrl);
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual('POST');
    expect(req.request.body).toEqual(newNumber);

    // Expect server to return the employee after POST
    const expectedResponse = new HttpResponse({ status: 201, statusText: 'Created', body: newNumber });
    // !! change this line !!
    req.flush(expectedResponse);
  })});
```